# Literal meaning of request

Tags: word-usage

How is the verb *request* taken equivalent to be *pleading or entreaty* in meaning?

Does it not mean *to question again? as (re-quest)?*

Comment: Etymology questions are off-topic here. See the [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Screengrab from dictionary]

[image: Screengrab from dictionary]

It looks like it is a latin origin word combining "re" and "quirere" which means to seek or search. Just as an FYI almost all dictionaries will give the etymology (word origins) of a word.